# How to define a function as vetorize in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, vectorization

I need to define a function as `vectorize`. Furthermore, the function must be `multithread` for a performance test. How does that option is added?

On the web I found 2 ways to `vectorize`:

1) redefinition:

```
function = pylab.vectorize(function)
```

2) Decorator:

```
@pylab.vectorize
def function(self): ....
```

This option does not work in my code, so I opted for the first one.

I found the following documentation, but does not help much:

1. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html
2. http://docs.continuum.io/numbapro/ufuncs.html

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say "This option does not work in my code"? The first and second options should behave in exactly the same way. What output are you getting when you call function() using the two options you presented? What output were you expecting?

Comment: I get the following error:
@pylab.vectorize 
NameError: name 'pylab' is not defined

Comment: You need to add `import pylab` at the top of the file.

Comment: Yes, i do that :)
Also, I expect a arary output of the comparison of 2 arrays in the vectorize function

Comment: Sorry, it was a error name. After the fix i've the following error:
/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1897, in _get_ufunc_and_otypes
    outputs = func(*inputs)
TypeError: function() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
The function definition is:
def function(self, arrar1):
I think the error is on vectorize over self instance... but i need it in funcion... :/

Comment: I think the key is to exclude "self" with:
excluded : set, optional
    Set of strings or integers representing the positional or keyword arguments for which the function will not be vectorized. These will be passed directly to pyfunc unmodified.